# Update python mac installation

Tags: python, macos, updates

I mistakenly deleted the old python installion on my system, i then downloaded the new python 3 release however when i type python into the terminal it still looks for it in the 2.7 directory. I looked through a few questions that said something about updating the path variable however ive had no luck, as to me it seems that python is only 4 files installed in the applications folder. I really would appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: What does it say if you type "which python | xargs ls -alh" in the terminal?

Comment: [Deleting the default Apple-provided Python is not good](http://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html): "The Apple-provided build of Python is installed in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework and /usr/bin/python, respectively. You should never modify or delete these, as they are Apple-controlled and are used by Apple- or third-party software."

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel    61K Jun 14 13:39 /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you reinstall your system from recovery mode. A lot of OSX software can rely on system python, even if it is not python projects. Then recomended way is use [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/). You can have different python (2.7, 3.3, pypy) versions the same time.

Comment: why not use macports or something similiar. I really hate installing software in non app form becuase then i have no idea how to delete it

Comment: Well i did a clean install anyway